# Why does Ansible not evaluate my jinja2 template variables inside a for loop?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

i am currently having a problem regarding jinja2 templating and ansible:
In my inventory.yaml I have something like this:

```yaml
all_hosts:
   vars:
      example_value: 150
   hosts:
      example_host_1:
         template_value: "host1: {{ example_value }}"
      example_host_2:
         template_value: "host2: {{ example_value }}"
```

In a playbook i now want to use "template_value" inside of a for loop like:

```yaml
...
- name: Debug
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: >
       { {% for x in all_hosts %}
          "{{ x.template_value }}"
       {% endfor %} }
```

I expect to see:
host1: 150
host2: 150

I, however, see:
host1: {{ example_value }}
host2: {{ example_value }}

Why is that? Can I explicitly evaluate the result of "x.template_value"?
While searching for a solution I read that {{}} inside of {{}} does not work.... ok but how do I get around that restriction? That must surely be possible.
Kind regards and thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have another approach using the **loop** and the **play_hosts** variable
Something like that :

```
- name: Debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[item].template_value }}"
  loop: "{{ play_hosts }}"
  run_once: true
```

Here is the output

```
TASK [test : Debug] ***********************************************************************
ok: [example_host_1] => (item=example_host_1) => {
    "msg": "host1: 150"
}
ok: [example_host_1] => (item=example_host_2) => {
    "msg": "host2: 150"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************
example_host_1             : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
example_host_2             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Does this solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the (simplified) inventory

```yaml
all:
   vars:
      var1: 150
   hosts:
      host1:
         tvar: "host1: {{ var1 }}"
      host2:
         tvar: "host2: {{ var1 }}"
```

Declare the dictionary

```yaml
  tvars: "{{ hostvars|
             json_query('*.tvar')|
             map('from_yaml')|combine }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  tvars:
    host1: 150
    host2: 150
```

The above expression always includes the variables *tvar* from all hosts in the inventory. Use the variable [*ansible_play_hosts_all*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) if you want to [*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) the variables from the active hosts only

```yaml
  tvars: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
             map('extract', hostvars, 'tvar')|
             map('from_yaml')|combine }}"
```

Notes:

- The value of *tvar* is a string. You can use the filter *from_yaml* to convert it to a dictionary if you want to. If you want to keep the strings remove *map('from_yaml')* from the pipe.
- The output to the screen depends on the [callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) and on the [template](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#). For example the callback [*yaml*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/yaml_callback.html) and the template below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ tvars }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    host1: 150
    host2: 150
```

See:

- [Inventory basics](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups)
- [Information about Ansible: magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables)

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    tvars: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.tvar')|map('from_yaml')|combine }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: tvar

    - debug:
        var: tvars
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  tvar: 'host1: 150'
ok: [host2] => 
  tvar: 'host2: 150'

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  tvars:
    host1: 150
    host2: 150

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Your code can be fixed

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name: Debug
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
          {{ hostvars[host]['tvar'] }},
          {% endfor %}
          }
          {% endfilter %}
      run_once: true
```